# Get the DefaultMutableTreeNode associated with a a Treepath (exact one not temporary one)

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am trying to make a FTP program w/ GUI using Java! And I successfully developed a recursive algorithm to get all the files. 
Example File Structure. (each of the files,and folders are MutableTreeNodes)

```
~
-- Documnets
    -- file1.txt
    -- file2.txt
-- Pictures
    -- hi
       -- file3.txt
    -- file.txt
```

I have a TreePath object, and I have a fileName. I also have the whole MutableTreeNode associated with teh entire directory "~" (in this case). I need to find the exact object (that is associated with the TreePath).
Any help would be appreciated..

TreePath Example `[~,Documents]`

```
public static DefaultMutableTreeNode getFileStructure(FTPClient client,String workingPath,DefaultMutableTreeNode style )
{

try {

    FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles(workingPath);
    for (FTPFile file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode fileDirectory =new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getName());
           // System.out.println("\n Folder: " +file.toString());
            style.add(fileDirectory);

        //     System.out.println("Node Depth = " + style.getDepth());
            getFileStructure(client, workingPath + "/" + file.getName(),style);
        } else {


        DefaultMutableTreeNode root =new DefaultMutableTreeNode();  

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Working Path: " + workingPath);
        System.out.println("Filename: " + file.getName());

        /// Convert variable (workingPath) to TreePath

        /// Add node to TreePath

        MutableTreeNode node = buildNodeFromString(workingPath);
        MutableTreeNode lastLeaf = node.getLastLeaf();
        TreePath path = new TreePath(lastLeaf.getPath());
        System.out.println("Path =" + path);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent();





       // style.remove(parentNode);

        MutableTreeNode fileDirectory =new MutableTreeNode(file.getName());
        // parentNode.add(fileDirectory);
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) jt.getModel();
        model.insertNodeInto(fileDirectory,parentNode,parentNode.getChildCount());
       // model.reload(parentNode);

        style.add(parentNode);

        model.reload(style);

        System.out.println("Added to node = " + parentNode.toString());
       // System.out.println("First Node = " + i.getFirstChild().toString());
        //System.out.println("Last Node = " + i.getLastChild().toString());
        System.out.println("Num of Children = " + parentNode.getLeafCount());
        System.out.println("Depth Count= " + style.getDepth());

        //    return i;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("IOException:" + ex);
 } 



 return style;
}
```

The 'else' part contains the code im trying to get to work. Thish part is responsible for 1) finding the node (folder) and creating a DefaultMutableTreeNode for that folder, and add the file node to that folder node...

Comment: The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html) have a pretty good example , basically `DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)selectedPath.getLastPathComponent()).
       getUserObject();` but we’d need a lot more context to be able to provide you more support - like the source of the `TreePath` and what’s “temporary” mean?

Comment: ok i will post that, temporary means creating a new node for every file in a folder...for example, if I have 3 text files in a folder, then this program would create 3 "Documents" folder (one for every file)

Comment: Also @MadProgrammer could you give an example how you would use that? I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my "for" loop was misplaced....